# Spark RDD to Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Below is the data in a file

```
PREFIX|Description|Destination|Num_Type
1|C1|IDD|NA
7|C2|IDDD|NA
20|C3|IDDD|NA
27|C3|IDDD|NA
30|C5|IDDD|NA
```

I am trying to read it and convert into Dataframe.

```
val file=sc.textFile("/user/cloudera-scm/file.csv")
val list=file.collect.toList
list.toDF.show

+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|PREFIX|Descriptio...|
|         1|C1|IDD|NA|
|        7|C2|IDDD|NA|
|       20|C3|IDDD|NA|
|       27|C3|IDDD|NA|
|       30|C5|IDDD|NA|
+--------------------+
```

I am not able to convert this to datafram with exact table form

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider your code.

```scala
// reading a potentially big file
val file=sc.textFile("/user/cloudera-scm/file.csv")
// collecting everything to the driver
val list=file.collect.toList
// converting a local list to a dataframe (this does not work)
list.toDF.show
```

There are ways to make your code work, but the very logic awkward. You are reading data with the executors, putting all of it on the driver to simply convert it to a dataframe (back to the executors). That's a lot of network communication, and the driver will most likely run out of memory for any reasonably large dataset.

What you can do it read the data directly as a dataframe like this (the driver does nothing and there is no unnecessary IO):

```scala
spark.read
    .option("sep", "|") // specify the delimiter
    .option("header", true) // to tell spark that there is a header
    .option("inferSchema", true) // optional, infer the types of the columns
    .csv(".../data.csv").show
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|PREFIX|Description|Destination|Num_Type|
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|     1|         C1|        IDD|      NA|
|     7|         C2|       IDDD|      NA|
|    20|         C3|       IDDD|      NA|
|    27|         C3|       IDDD|      NA|
|    30|         C5|       IDDD|      NA|
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Oli, but I  am reading from kafka stream, which is ultimately coming as DStream .Converting Dstream to RDD[String] which need to be converted to dataStream

Comment: If you replace `read` by `readStream`, I'm pretty sure it would work as well. Take a look at this for examples https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html